# Verifying the divergance theorem of a cube.

Tags: calculus, vectors

**Verify that the divergence theorem holds for the unit cube 0
< x <
1, 0
< y <
1,
0
< z <
1 and the vector field
v
(
x,y,z
) =
x
^
2
i
+ 2
z
sin(
πy
)
j
−
πz
2
cos(
πy
)
k**

Usually I could answer this question however I am only familiar on how to do this if the constraints of the cube used less than or equal to sign like 0≤ x≤ 1 0≤ y≤ 1 and 0≤ z≤ 1.

So you would calculate the flux of each face and find the summnation e.g. FACE 1: x=0 0≤y≤1 0≤z≤1 and the outgoing normal vector n=-i and then so on.

As the assigment question doesn't include 0 or include 1, do i need to alter the x,y,z values of my faces?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you use the closed cube (with $\le$) or the open cube (with $<$): the boundary is the same, and the integral of the divergence over the cube is the same.